# How to force RFC3339 string for all datetime for queries upon display as API?

Tags: datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using Cake 3.2.4

## What am I getting now?

Whenever a query is executed and there is a datetime field, it will be displayed as RFC2822 string.

e.g. `"2016-07-18T09:00:00+0800"`

## What do I want?

I want RFC 3339 string

e.g. `"2016-07-18T09:00:00+08:00"`

## What did I try?

```
        $paginationQuery->formatResults(function (\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface $results) {
            return $results->map(function ($row) {
                $datetime =  $row['start_date'];
                $row['start_date'] = $datetime->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);
                return $row;
            });
        });
```

I kinda forced the original datetime object to display as string.

## Okay, so what's wrong?

I am unsure if it's wrong to do so. As you can see clearly, the original value for $row['start_date'] is actually a datetime object. Not a string.

Can I keep the value as datetime object but when it gets displayed as api, it uses the RFC3339 format?

Comment: Do you want _all_ date/time objects in your application to be affected? Where and how exactly do you "display" them?

Comment: See https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/8571